# Azure VM generalized

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

I created an image of a VM without having done the Sysprep procedures. I now have a problem, i. e. a VM that is generalized and should not be and that when I create a VM using my image I have this message:

Failed to start virtual machine'X'. Error: OS Provisioning for VM'X' did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for use as an image

Now I cannot use this Image to create any VM since I didn't followed the proper guide to do so. What I'll like to know is, is there a way to de-generalized the VM?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an 'Image' without sysprep.  If you do not sysprep VM you can use it as a specialized disk but not an image.

Some infromation to help you:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized#option-2-upload-a-specialized-vhd

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image#determine-when-to-use-sysprep-

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized-portal